# Why doesn't color option (of a TikZ node) work with flushright, center or flushleft?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, color

Why isn't the text inside the `flushright`, `center` or `flushleft` environments red?

```
\documentclass[tikz,preview=true]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \node at (1,1) [text width=3cm, color=red] {%
            This is red
            \begin{flushright}
                With flushright this is not!    
            \end{flushright}
            \begin{center}
                The same with center\dots    
            \end{center}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \dots or flushleft!    
            \end{flushleft}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Same happens with `center` and `flushleft`.

Comment: Using a different method, `font=\color{red}`, works.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you, your method works, if you transform your comment into an answer with a brief explanation of the reason, I'll accept it.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question though, and I can't give an explanation.

Comment: @PaulGaborit opened an issue back in the day in the PGF repository about the same issue but I didn't check what happened afterwards

Comment: @Ignasi I've edited the question to include what you pointed out in your comment, thank you!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Box options are not related to this problem try for example `\node[text=blue]{blue \textcolor{red}{red} blue};`. As I mentioned this bug is already reported somewhere in the realms of sourceforge

Comment: The issue is still there: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/362/

Comment: @percusse Interesting: with your `\node[text=blue]{blue \textcolor{red}{red} blue}` the second blue is black!

Comment: Yes because the first insertion of color is lost after textcolor fiddles with it and it resorts back to original. It is a pretty involved issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately this site will show *lots* of issues with tikz colour. Basically the problem is that it doesn't use driver or engine specific colour support it just pushes in back end colour. It's a lot easier to see what the problem is than to see how to fix (tikz is not the smallest package on ctan).

In this case you generate

```
...............\pdfliteral{1 0 0 RG }
...............\pdfliteral{1 0 0 rg }
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 T
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 h
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 s
...............\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 s
...............\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 r
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 d
...............\penalty 10000
...............\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...............\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 20.00003
..............\penalty -51
..............\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0
..............\glue(\parskip) 0.0
..............\glue(\baselineskip) 5.05556
..............\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x85.35826, glue set 49.19188fil
...............\glue(\leftskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...............\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
................\glue 0.0
................\glue 0.0
................\glue -5.0
................\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.................\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 g 0 G}
.................\pdfcolorstack 0 pop
................\glue 5.0
...............\penalty 0
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 T
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 h
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 s
...............\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
...............\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 !
```

Where you see that the item handling has used an empty box and pushed and popped the colour state.

```
.................\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 g 0 G}
.................\pdfcolorstack 0 pop
```

so that should put the colour back to what it was, but actually it puts the colour back to *the last colour pushed on to the colour stack*  But Tikz never pushed red, it did

```
...............\pdfliteral{1 0 0 RG }
...............\pdfliteral{1 0 0 rg }
```

so pdftex doesn't "know" that is red at all it is just a literal pdf string written to the output file, so when pdftex generates pdf from the `\pdfcolorstack 0 pop` it generates *black*.....

Comment: Try it with PS :)

Comment: @percusse essentially the same issue with latex+dvips: the red is added as literal postscript `............\special{ps:: 1 0 0 setrgbcolor }
` so dvips does not know it is colour so when it generates postscript from the color pop special the colour is lost `..............\special{color push gray 0}
..............\special{color pop}`

Comment: This explanation is much more detailed than what I meant by requesting it to @TorbjørnT. Thank you!

Comment: Yes and, if I'm not mistaken which very possible, otherwise the color distinction would have problems while drawing red filling blue and writing in yellow.

Comment: @percusse yes that's why it's not easy to fix, the drivers only have one colour stack so basically push the fill and draw colours together so it's easy to see why it goes wrong but not that clear what tikz should do, although in cases like this where there are no separate fill colours specified it could probably push/pop the colours, perhaps...

Comment: I _think_ (not entirely sure) that all the color stuff in PGF/TikZ was changed to enable support for the SVG backend. Certainly it used to be the case that `\color` was used internally by TikZ. And  by using `\let\pgfsetcolor=\color` in the preamble the OP's problem disappears.